# ASP.NET Web API with Google OpenID Connect

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, owin, openid-connect

**Goal:**
I would like to protect my web service (ASP.NET Web API using OWIN) with OpenID Connect. The Identity Provider is Google.

**Important:**
I'm only responsible for the web service. I DO NOT have any Web Application (no UI; this is up to 3rd parties using my web service).

**Considerations:**
As my web service runs on a server I think it's best to use Authorization Code Flow (or Hybrid?).

**What's done so far**:
I configured OWIN (in my web service) to use OpenID Connect (`UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`).

**Current behavior:**
I someone unauthorized tries to access the web service, the web service redirects her (sending a 302) to Google. As I don't have a UI it's up to 3rd parties to properly display the consent page. Let's assume the user agrees and presses "Accept".

An here I'm stuck... As far as I understand Google sends back an Authorization Code (which my web service could use to get an Access Token). How can I get an hand on the Authorization Code? Does Google even support the Authorization Code Flow (`ResponseType = code`)?

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = "aClientId",
    ClientSecret = "aClientSecret",
    Authority = "https://accounts.google.com/",
    RedirectUri = "do I need this??",  //I guess here I would register a resources... but what to do in there?
    ResponseType =  "code",            //does Google even support code??
    Scope = "openid",                
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
        {
            var code = context.Code; //I never got to this point so far
            //do stuff
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    },
});
```

Do I have to call Google manually (to get the Access Token) and then SignIn (using `GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);`) or does OWIN middleware take care of this?

Update:
A repro is here: https://github.com/Dunken/WebApiOpenIdConnect

Comment: google is dropping openid for new clients. When signing in with google use OAUTH instead.

Comment: This is about OpenID Connect (OAuth based) and not OpenID.

Comment: Google supports the Authorization Code grant.

Comment: yes Google supports response type code.    Its the first request.  Its basically a web page that is displayed to the user.  Once they accept that returns an authentication code show in the browser and in the title of the browser.  its up to you to get it back from the browser into your application.  why not use the google-dotnet client lib?

Comment: The 3rd parties using your web service `must` send the authorization code to your service after retrieving it from Google.